# What do the red and green dots mean on the property symbol in Structure view in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

What do the red and green dots in the lower left of the symbol indicate?

[image: Red and green dots on symbols]

The [documentation for symbols in IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html) / Android Studio does not mention their meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Green = getter, red = setter.

If I have

```
private boolean mBacon = false;

public boolean getBacon() {
    return mBacon;
}

public void setBacon(boolean b) {
    mBacon = b;
}
```

I get

[image: mmm bacon]